# refresh ListView after delete from database

Tags: android, database, listview

I have a ListView with a SimpleCursorAdapter,it load informations from a database,I want onlongclicklistener to delete an item from database,it works fine,but the list does not refreshes,I tried with listView.refreshDrawableState(); and some other methods that I found as answer but no one works,this is my onCreate function:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_act);
    imzero = (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.iv_zero_pers);
    tvzero = (TextView)findViewById (R.id.tv_zero_pers);
    dbConnector = new DatabaseConnectorrso(MyListActivity.this);
    dbConnector.checkCursor();
    if (DatabaseConnector.de)//check if database is emplty
    {
    try{                
        dbConnector.open();             
        dbConnector.load();//load information from database
        dbConnector.close();
        imzero.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvzero.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        dbConnector.close();
    }
    conAdapter =(new ImageAndTextAdapter(MyListActivity.this,
            R.layout.meniu_lista_element, null, null, null));
    setListAdapter(conAdapter);
    }
    else{
        dbConnector.close();
        imzero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvzero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

and I tried to refresh the list like this

```
   listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            deleteDialog(Integer.parseInt (DatabaseConnector.id.get(position))); //delete from database 
            dbConnector.checkCursor();
            if (DatabaseConnector.de)
            {
            try{                
                dbConnector.open();             
                dbConnector.loadPersoane();
                listView.refreshDrawableState();
                dbConnector.close();
                imzero.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tvzero.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                dbConnector.close();
            }
            conAdapter =(new ImageAndTextAdapter(AltePersoane.this,
                    R.layout.meniu_lista_element, null, null, null));
            setListAdapter(conAdapter);
            }
            else{
                dbConnector.close();
                imzero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvzero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Requery the database, get the new cursor and then do notify data set changed on the listview

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or

```
yourAdapter.getCursor().requery();
```

**Update**:

I think you're doing something wrong, try this:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        deleteDialog(Integer.parseInt (DatabaseConnector.id.get(position))); //delete from database 
        dbConnector.checkCursor();
        if (DatabaseConnector.de)
        {
        try{                
            dbConnector.open();             
            dbConnector.loadPersoane();
                                //Removed
            dbConnector.close();
            imzero.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvzero.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            dbConnector.close();
        }
        conAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else{
            dbConnector.close();
            imzero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvzero.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I have to wrote this line before setListAdapter?

Comment: you don't have to set the adapter again. Remove those lines.

Comment: still not works,with Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); nothings happen and with yourAdapter.getCursor().requery(); app stops

Comment: I solved it,i made an intent from this activity to the same activity and it's ok

Comment: that will re-create your whole activity, your app's performance would compromised...

Comment: That doesn't sound like an ideal solution, to have to go away from the Activity and come back. Can you pause the app during `requery()` and see where it's hanging?

Comment: i know that app's performance can be compromised but I can't find another way

Comment: i tried as you said ThePCWizard,but the result is the same,nothing happens

Answer (score -1):

try to intent activity from your activity to the same,it can work

```
    Intent i = new Intent (MyActivity.this,MyActivity.class);
    startActivity (i);
```

Comment: its call your activity again and again... if i do this many times then?? Please do not suggest this type of stuff.

Comment: yes there is many ways available to do this without call intent. after delete call onCreate(); method it will do same thing without intent. second way is below check ThePCWizard's answer. Cursor ll automatically doing same thing.