# Update SQlite database on click of a textview in single item of listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with a textview in each row. I am using a custom adapter to populate the each textview for different listview items from database, which also has a holder.textview.onclicklistener on the textview.

Problem is that I want to update database on click of textview for different list items, but getContentResolver() method, used to update the database does not work in holder.textview.onclicklistener.

Any ideas on how to update the database on click of textview present in listview items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `Context` instance to call `getContentResolver()`. You can get one from the `View` that is passed to the `onClick()` method,  i.e.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        ContentResolver cr = v.getContext().getContentResolver();
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hence you show nothing in your code, this might be a great help of updating your database items;

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

and for updating the listview this will be great thread;

[refresh ListView after delete from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859043/refresh-listview-after-delete-from-database)

Hope it helps u. Cheers!